# Push.jsを使ってのニュース通知等について

Tags: javascript, push-notification

サイトのニュース等をWebプッシュを使用して行いたいと考えております。

探したところPush.jsというライブラリがあるようです。
https://github.com/Nickersoft/push.js

ライブラリの使い方を見るとPush実行がクライアント側javascriptトリガになっており
閲覧しているページ内のjavascriptで動作できる範囲の通知しかできないように思えます。

想定としては、サーバ側からPushを投げ通知を許可したユーザに対してPushが行われることを想定しているのですが、Push.jsはそのような動作はできないのでしょうか？

Push.jsを紹介している日本語サイトは検索してもそれなりにありますが
「ウェブサイトで更新があったときなどに通知」「サイトからお知らせ」等の用途として紹介されていたりしますが、
Push.jsでその様なサーバ側トリガのPushは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push.jsは[Notifications API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/)を簡単に使えるようにしたライブラリで、それ自身にサーバと通信する機能は備えていません。

対象のWebページを開いたままサーバトリガーで通知を表示するための通信方法はいくつか考えられます。

- [WebSocket](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/)
- [Server-Sent Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-eventsource-20090421/)
- [ロングポーリング](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93#Long_polling)

どれを使用するかは想定している環境などに依ります。